# i18n in Cakephp 3 + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, internationalization, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to solve this in the prettiest possible way, i've integrated cakephp in wordpress or wordpress in cakephp that's a matter of how you see it.

The wordpress installation exists in the Cakephp /webroot directory and is loaded first by some .htaccess trickery and the Cakephp is mapped to a specific subdomain or folder.

The issue i'm having here is that the Cakephp & Wordpress i18n/translate functions are the same, `function __()`.

I've solved this temporarily by simply declaring CakePHP's `__()` function to `___()`.

> vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/i18n/functions.php

```
if (!function_exists('__')) {
    /**
     * Returns a translated string if one is found; Otherwise, the submitted message.
     *
     * @param string $singular Text to translate.
     * @param mixed $args Array with arguments or multiple arguments in function.
     * @return mixed Translated string.
     * @link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#__
     */
    function __($singular, $args = null)
    {
        if (!$singular) {
            return;
        }

        $arguments = func_num_args() === 2 ? (array)$args : array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
        return I18n::translator()->translate($singular, $arguments);
    }

}
else
{
    function ___($singular, $args = null)
    {
        if (!$singular) {
            return;
        }

        $arguments = func_num_args() === 2 ? (array)$args : array_slice(func_get_args(), 1);
        return I18n::translator()->translate($singular, $arguments);
    }
}
```

> wp-includes/i10n.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve the translation of $text. If there is no translation,
 * or the text domain isn't loaded, the original text is returned.
 *
 * @since 2.1.0
 *
 * @param string $text   Text to translate.
 * @param string $domain Optional. Text domain. Unique identifier for retrieving translated strings.
 * @return string Translated text.
 */
function __( $text, $domain = 'default' ) {
    return translate( $text, $domain );
}
```

So my question is, is this the best way to solve the problem or should i try to move all the Cakephp Translations to Wordpress? Don't really like changing the Cakephp Core since it will crash at updates for example. Any ideas?

Comment: I am facing a situation in which I have to display WordPress posts into cakephp 3 site. I have combined database of WordPress with Cakephp database and put the wp folder into webroot. Can you please help me what are the rest steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not declare the functions before the cakephp core is loaded? That is, load the file in wordpress that declares the translation functions and then declare your override of the cakephp functions.

```
include wordpress/file_having_translation_functions;
function ___(...) {
    return I18n::...;
}
```

Comment: Wordpress functions are loaded first the Cakephp transl.function is overridden, i could do the opposite though but that would result in crashing the wp translation functionality, and thats bad.

Comment: Then that is perfect. You can just declare the new translation functions yourself in your cakephp app bootstrap

Comment: That's right alot better to put the code in bootstrap instead of Core files :) thank you.